# What is the difference between tensordot and einsum in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

For my understanding, tensordot 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html
is multiply two tensors and sum given indices. This is precisely einsum does.

Actually what is the difference between this two functions? Is that due to different performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are different approaches to similar problems.  `einsum` is more general.  Speed can be similar, though you need to check individual cases.

`tensordot` works by reshaping and transposing axes, reducing the problem to one that `np.dot` can solve.  Its code, up to the `dot` call is Python, so you can read it for yourself.

`einsum` is built 'from-ground-up' to work with the 'Einstein notation' that is used in physics (it was written by scientist for fit his needs and usage).  The documentation covers that.  It is C code, so is a little harder to study.  Basically it parses the indexing string, and builds an `nditer` object that will iterate over the input arrays, performing some sort of sum-of-products calculation.  It can take short cuts in case where you just want indexing, diagonal, etc.

There have been number of questions asking about either of these functions, or suggesting their use in the answers.

In new versions there is also a `np.matmul` that generalized `dot` in a different way.  It is linked to the new `@` operator in Python3.5.